# Reinstalling Ubuntu 15.10: "Removing conflicting operating system files" has been running for almost 24 hours

Tags: system-installation, 15.10

The process is not stuck because the terminal shows "progress", it keeps trying to remove files that it can't find, the messages read something like: `/..../file x: Warning: Source ID XXXXXX was not found when attempting to remove it`

The reason I am reinstalling is because my installation was messed up when I installed `ubuntu-touch` and the system wouldn't reboot.

I was able to fire up a live USB through grub and start the installation process, I figured it would be possible to simply reinstall but it seems to be taking forever. Is this normal behavior? Should I stop it and simply go with a fresh install instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main question is: do you have a separate `/home` partition?
If so then just erase your `/` and leave `/home` untouched, just set mountpoint to it.

If not and there is some important files then I recommend you mount your partition and remove everything except `/home`, e.g.

```
fdisk -l
```

Examine the output and find appropriate device name

```
mount /dev/sdaXY /mnt  # use the device name from fdisk -l here
mkdir /mnt/2rm         # create working dir
mv /mnt/* /mnt/2rm     # move all dirs to work dir
mv /mnt/2rm/home /mnt  # return home back
rm -rfv /mnt/2rm       # now we can safely delete the rest
```

After the above manipulations you can easily install Ubuntu on the same partition. Ubiquity, the Ubuntu installer, will [preserve](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityPreserveHome) your `/home` directory.

Comment: Yes I have `/` on an SSD and `/home` on a HDD

Comment: So you can just easely erase SSD and leave HDD unformated. It's much quickly.

Comment: Did it work @PepePaez

Comment: @TamsynMichael yes it did, I just erased the SSD and left everything untouched on my HDD, my computer has been working without issues

Comment: Thanks!  I did the same, I did have to reinstall software, but all my data is still there.  :)

Comment: Exactly the same problem in 2018 with Ubuntu18.4. I can hardly believe Ubuntu is still unable to figure out / and “reinstall” itself.